# XPATH select nodes with multiple child values partial matching

Tags: php, xml, xpath

i would like to select element, that has few childs with specific values. Here is example of xml: `

```
<events>
  <event>
    <startDateTime>2012-12-0128090</startDateTime>
    <homeTeam>
      <name>TEST123</name>
    </homeTeam>
  </event>
</events>`
```

Result i want is event, that contains startDateTime with value 2012-12-01 and contains TEST value of homeTeam/Name.

I am trying like this:

```
//events/event[startDateTime[contains(.,'2012-12-01')] and homeTeam/name[contains(.,'TEST')]]');
```

This returns me also events with starDateTime different from specified.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tweaked your XML and XPath slightly

```
<events>
    <event>
        <startDateTime>2012-12-0128090</startDateTime>
        <homeTeam>
            <name>TEST123</name>
        </homeTeam>
    </event>
    <event>
        <startDateTime>*2013-12-0128090*</startDateTime>
        <homeTeam>
            <name>TEST123</name>
        </homeTeam>
    </event>
</events>
```

I then used the following XPath to access the second node:

```
//events/event[(startDateTime[contains(.,'2013-12-01')]) and (homeTeam/name[contains(.,'TEST')])]
```

I also tested it with different name values, and it seems to work fine.